# pyodbc connect to MS Access on SFTP

Tags: python, ms-access, sftp, pyodbc, pysftp

I want to read MS Access files from an SFTP server. The `pyodbc` syntax for reading MS Access files is:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" + r"Dbq=file_path;")
```

In this case the `file_path` is on the SFTP. I can download the SFTP files to my local and then connect to the Access db, but is it possible to connect directly to the SFTP.

I have tried using `pysftp` library without any success-

```
import pysftp
import pyodbc
with pysftp.Connection(sftp_credentials['SERVER'], username=sftp_credentials['USERNAME'],
                           password= sftp_credentials['PASSWORD'], port = sftp_credentials['PORT'],
                           cnopts = cnopts) as sftp:
    with sftp.open(file) as f:
        conn = pyodbc.connect(r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" + r"Dbq=f;")
```

Are there any alternatives to downloading SFTP files to local.

Answer (score 2):

> but is it possible to connect directly to the SFTP

No, not unless you have some sort of software to make an SFTP connection look like a regular mapped drive/folder. (I am not aware of any such software.)

Comment: _is it possible to connect directly to the SFTP?_ Definitely not.